Does a landlord have to inform prospective tenants if the property has a dark history?
Say several years ago there was a grisly murder/crime at my property, the kind that will spook most people and lead the more superstitious to say the property is haunted. I've cleaned the place up and it's no longer possible to tell that there was a crime from the physical evidence, but there're plenty of historical details that one can find online or in old newspapers.
I'm renting the property out. Am I legally obliged to tell prospective tenants that the property has a dark history?
I have no particular jurisdiction in mind.

Tenants, not buyers?

@o.m. it says "renting the property out", and "tenants".

@WeatherVane, yes, but concealing something to affect the value of a sold property might be different from concealing something which does not affect the usefulness.

united-states
You can find a state-by-state description of the disclosure rules at Does your state require you to disclose a death in your home or rental property?
In general, the requirements seem to be the same when selling and renting.

FWIW, I agree that the entry in the link for Colorado (which provides by statute that this need not be disclosed) is correct.

Yes
new-south-wales
The law requires the disclosure of all material facts which includes if it:

has been the scene of a serious violent crime (e.g. murder or aggravated assault) in the last five years
has been used to manufacture or cultivate a prohibited drug or prohibited plant in the last two years

Among other things.
